# Code refactoring in PyCharm backslash style for wrapped lines

Tags: python, pycharm

In the past PyCharm refactored long string like that:

```
long_string = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

to this:

```
long_string = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" \
              "aaaaaaaa"
```

Since I updated the PyCharm IDE it starts to refactor long string to be:

```
long_string = ("aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
               "aaaaaaa")
```

I want to return to the backslash style.

I searched in the setting and didn't find.

PyCharm version: 2023.2

Comment: FWIW, the second way is the PEP8 style-guide preferred way: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

Comment: Ok thanks for sharing, but since I work on large project I prefer not to change the code style yet.